# Pergunta para SQL Server - Código

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, ssms

Quais os nomes dos pilotos que fizeram um tempo inferior a '1:12' na 1ª volta da 2ª prova?

- Como posso fazer os tempos de cada volta?
- Terei de fazer uma nova tabela?

As tabelas de SQL Server criadas foram as seguintes:

```
CREATE TABLE Carro(
IdCarro INT NOT NULL,
Marca VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Modelo VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (IdCarro));

CREATE TABLE Piloto(
IdPiloto INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Morada VARCHAR(50),
Telefone INT,
PRIMARY KEY (IdPiloto));

CREATE TABLE Equipa(
IdEquipa INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20),
Morada VARCHAR(50),
Telefone INT,
PRIMARY KEY (IdEquipa));

CREATE TABLE Patrocinador(
IdPatrocinador INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL,
Morada VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (IdPatrocinador));

CREATE TABLE Prova(
IdProva INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Local VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Data DATE NOT NULL,
NrVoltas INT NOT NULL,
MelhorTempo TIME,
PRIMARY KEY (IdProva));

CREATE TABLE EquipaParticipaProva(
IdEquipa INT NOT NULL,
IdCarro INT NOT NULL,
IdPiloto INT NOT NULL,
IdProva INT NOT NULL,
TempoPorVolta TIME,
TempoFinal TIME,
PosicaoRelativa INT,
PosicaoFinal INT,
FOREIGN KEY (IdProva) REFERENCES Prova(IdProva),
FOREIGN KEY (IdCarro) REFERENCES Carro(IdCarro),
FOREIGN KEY (IdPiloto) REFERENCES Piloto(IdPiloto),
PRIMARY KEY (IdEquipa,IdPiloto,IdCarro));

CREATE TABLE PatrocinadorOficial(
IdPatrocinador INT NOT NULL,
IdProva INT NOT NULL,
Valor MONEY NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (IdProva) REFERENCES Prova(IdProva),
PRIMARY KEY (IdPatrocinador, IdProva));

CREATE TABLE PatrocinadorNaoOficial(
IdPatrocinador INT NOT NULL,
IdProva INT NOT NULL,
Valor MONEY NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (IdProva) REFERENCES Prova(IdProva),
PRIMARY KEY (IdPatrocinador, IdProva));

CREATE TABLE Mecanico(
IdMecanico INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20),
Morada VARCHAR(50),
Telefone INT,
PRIMARY KEY (IdMecanico));

CREATE TABLE Afinacao(
IdAfinacao INT NOT NULL,
IdMecanico INT NOT NULL,
IdEquipa INT NOT NULL,
TipoAfinacao VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
TempoDespendido TIME,
Data DATE NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (IdEquipa) REFERENCES Equipa(IdEquipa),
FOREIGN KEY (IdMecanico) REFERENCES Mecanico(IdMecanico),
PRIMARY KEY (IdAfinacao));
```

"Inserts" colocados para teste:

```
INSERT INTO Carro
VALUES (1, 'Nissan', 'Skyline');

INSERT INTO Carro
VALUES (2, 'Subaru', 'Impreza');

INSERT INTO Carro
VALUES (3, 'Mitsubishi', 'Evolution');

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (111, 'Carlos Simão', 'Castelo Branco', 111111111);

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (112, 'Paulo Solipa', 'Castelo Branco', 111111112);

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (113, 'JaGanhou', 'Lisboa', 111111113); 

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (114, 'AsdoVolante', 'Lisboa', 111111114);

INSERT INTO Equipa
VALUES (001, 'OsAtolados', 'Castelo Branco', 272722123);

INSERT INTO Equipa
VALUES (002, 'Sparco', 'Lisboa', 212312432); 

INSERT INTO Equipa
VALUES (003, 'ESTeam', 'Castelo Branco', 272343573);

INSERT INTO Prova
VALUES (010, 'RallycrossCB', 'Castelo Branco', '2017-02-02', 4, '00:04:23');

INSERT INTO EquipaParticipaProva
VALUES (002, 3, 113, 010, '00:01:20', '00:04:40', 3, 3);

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOR
VALUES(921, 'IPCB', 'Av da Talagueira');

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOR
VALUES(922, 'Bells Bar', 'Praceta Qualquer Coisa');

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOR
VALUES(923, 'MonsterEnergy', 'USA');

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOR
VALUES(924, 'Sical', 'Lisboa');

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOROFICIAL
VALUES(923, 010, 10000);

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOROFICIAL
VALUES(921, 11, 8000);

INSERT INTO PATROCINADORNAOOFICIAL
VALUES(920, 010, 5000);

INSERT INTO PATROCINADORNAOOFICIAL
VALUES(922, 11, 3000);

INSERT INTO PATROCINADORNAOOFICIAL
VALUES(924, 10, 6000);

INSERT INTO EQUIPAPARTICIPAPROVA
VALUES(1, 3, 111, 11, '00:01:00', '00:10:00', 1, 1);

INSERT INTO Prova
VALUES (11, 'RallyLels', 'Bells', '2017-03-04', 10, '00:10:00');

INSERT INTO MECANICO
VALUES(333, 'Zacarias','Leiria',933628487);

INSERT INTO MECANICO
VALUES(334, 'Zé', 'Bragança', 963628487);

INSERT INTO MECANICO
VALUES(335, 'Luís', 'Lisboa', 913628487);

INSERT INTO AFINACAO
VALUES(20, 333, 001, 'Travões', '1:00:00', '2017-02-03');

INSERT INTO AFINACAO
VALUES(21, 334, 002, 'Luzes', '00:15:00', '2017-02-03');

INSERT INTO AFINACAO
VALUES(22, 335, 003, 'Travoes', '1:00:00', '2017-02-01');
```

Comment: em qual tabela você guarda o tempo de cada volta ? afinação ?

Comment: Pois é essa a minha questão @RovannLinhalis . Não sei como hei-de guardar o tempo de cada volta pois este pode variar. Inicialmente tinha colocado o tempo por volta na tabela EquipaParticipaProva, mas após deparar-me com esta pergunta reparei que o mesmo não seria possível e o meu raciocinio estava errado.

Comment: certo, para pensar no banco de dados, um modelo ER ajuda muito. Vou tentar fazer algo com base no que você tem

Comment: Muito Obrigado @RovannLinhalis . Agradeço imenso a sua ajuda. Eu tinha feito o modelo ER mas mesmo assim não consegui :/

Comment: Tentei aproveitar seu script no SQLFiddle mas não deu certo, então fiz algo bem simples que talvez te ajude com sua lógica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz algo bem simples para tentar te ajudar primeiro com a estrutura do seu banco, depois veremos os comandos SQL para isso.

[image: Modelo ER]

Veja o modelo e qualquer dúvida, só falar. Fiz bem simples e obviamente sem as particularidades das suas necessidades.

Comment: Deixe ver se percebi então: tenho de modificar a minha tabela EquipaParticipaProva sendo que a Primary Key ficará IdInscricao e criar a tabela volta com o IdVolta como Primary Key e como Foreign Key IdInscricao e assim consigo guardar os tempos de cada volta. Consegui perceber bem? @RovannLinhalis  Mas assim sendo como guardo o tempo de várias voltas de várias corridas. Por exemplo idvolta 1, 2,3 correspondem a 3 voltas da 1ªa corrida e tenho uma 2ª corrida com 4 voltas. Não posso guardar com o mesmo Id.

Comment: A chave primária é composta pelo id da inscrição é número da volta, em uma outra corrida, terra outra inscrição, podendo ter outras voltas, mas lembre-se este é bem simples, se tivesse um campeonato por exemplo, a inscrição seria no campeonato e não na corrida